# How to reformat a Mac with a usb drive?

Tags: macos, boot, mac, usb, bootable-media

I'm trying to reformat a Mac Pro, but the thing is that my Mac belong to the older version(2006) and the previous System Admin that help to set it up didn't leave behind the password. My boss wants to use these old machine as additional machines in a computer lab.

I've found this article on how to create a bootable USB drive http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/30/create-os-x-el-capitan-boot-install-drive/. The problem is that I can't use the USB method because Macs won't allow me boot from them.

One of the Mac has a folder and a "?" sign when I login and the other is encrypted I think. I can't use the "Press the option key while the machine is starting" and the CMD and R doesn't work either for some reason. It is running Mac OS X 10.8.4.1.

Is there any solution or these two Macs are bricked?

Comment: "Press [any boot combo] while the machine is starting" - do it right after the chimes. If you're hesitant or too early, it'll skip past. If you don't have another Mac you can work from, then getting a Snow Leopard CD from Apple would be the simplest method to get them working; you can update after that. Early Mac Pros are notoriously difficult to boot from USB, they really want a CD. If you can get to Recovery, there's a method to reset passwords, but not if the drive is encrypted. Drop a comment as to where you can get & let's work further. Also clarify current OS, 10.8.4.1 isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to remove the hard drives and put them in an enclosure connected to another machine. You could then wipe the disks and install a fresh copy of OS X on to them.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. I think it should work. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to boot it while holding either the command or option key to get it to boot from external media.